# Configure nginx to serve query string parameter

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have one NextJs site, with next export we get one out folder which we want to serve from Nginx.
In out/login there is one '[[...parameter]].html'.
When we deploy site using pm2 it is working if we hit url "serverIP:port/login/programID/applicant"

But when serving through nginx it is not working.

Below is the nginx configuration file content:

server{

```
    listen 7001;
    server_name server_ip;
    root /var/www/html/out/;
   location / {

            try_files $uri $uri.html  $uri.html/ =404;
   }
```

}

Please help. I am new to nginx so having some difficulties.

Comment: The config you have shown us is for a very simple origin server. If you want to apply some mapping between the path in the URL and the path on the filesystem, you're going to need some rules in nginx to define what that mapping should be.  If you can describe the problem accurately, providing explicit examples of the request URLs and the corresponding filesystem locations you might get some sensible answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Query string refers to GET parameters which you provide after URL e.g `?name=foo`. My guess is that you want to serve files in a directory instead, since you mention "out folder which we want to serve from Nginx".

---

In this case your example should work fine, but your **try_files** rule expects that you also provide the file name inside the URL.

So when you are requesting GET [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) then Nginx tries to find a
path inside the `root` directory with either name `/`, `.html`, `.html/` or fail with 404 error code. Path `.html/` refers to a directory named `.html` inside your root and is probably a mistake.

In case you have a file named `index.html` in your specified root directory then following requests would match for it:

- `GET www.mysite.com/index.html` (because of `$uri`)
- `GET www.mysite.com/index`      (because of `$uri.html`)

What you probably are looking for is this:

```
location / {
   root /var/www/html/out;
   index index.html index.htm;
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

This does following:

- Is there an actual file, specified by *$uri*, in your root directory - then serve this.
- Is there a directory path, specified by *$uri*, in your root directory?

  - If yes, check if it contains a file named *index.html* or *index.htm* - then serve this.
- None of the above, return 404.

So `GET www.mysite.com` would try to find a file `index.html` or `index.htm` inside your root.

---

In case you still mean query strings you could write something like this:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/html/out;
    try_files /$arg_file =404;
}
```

Then request like `GET www.mysite.com?file=index.html` would search for a file `index.html` inside your root. Nginx is awesome, isn't it?

---

Hope this helps :)

Also read more about [try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) and [Nginx Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).